# F2051 Unit JclUnitVersioning was compiled with a different version of System.Contnrs.TObjectList.Remove

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, jvcl, jedi-code-library

I'm migrating a Delphi 2 project to RAD Studio XE2.

When I try to compile I get

> [DCC Fatal Error] MyUnit.pas(9): F2051 Unit JclUnitVersioning was compiled with a different version of System.Contnrs.TObjectList.Remove

at the following row:

```
unit MyUnit;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, DB, DBTables, TB97, ExtCtrls, Grids, DBGrids, Vcl.Mask, JvExMask,
  Vcl.DBLookup,
  JvToolEdit,  {<-- error here}
  TB97Ctls;

{...}
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling RAD Studio, JCL and JVCL, but nothing changes.

**Update** Was using the binary Jedi [installer from A.Hausladen](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2011/11/updated-jcl-and-jvcl-binary-installers-for-xe2-2/) (intended for use in Delphi trial editions only).

Comment: Go to `Project / Options` menu item. In the Project Options dialog check if you have configured proper paths in `Search Path` section and if there are some which directs to the folders with your previous JCL installation, delete them and try to rebuild the project. If you don't find such directories in that section, try to go to `View / Project Manager` and right click over you project item and try to use `Clean` and then `Build`.

Comment: You've still got more crap lying around that merely uninstalling and reinstalling did not clean up.  Uninstalling did not clear your Delphi current-user's registry settings, nor did it format your hard drive, so it's possible that there are JCL-named DCU files somewhere around, that are messing you up. There is more "state" here to be addressed. See my answer. Search your drive for copies of `JclUnitVersioning.dcu`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either have old DCU files lying around that need to be rebuilt, or removed, or your project or library path contents are not consistent. (Find files named `JclUnitVersioning.dcu` that are not in the proper JCL Library folder, and remove them. The proper library folders are named `jcl\lib\d7`, through `jcl\lib\d16`, depending on your delphi version number )

This usually means that your project has access to both a directory that is in your library-path (or project search path) that contains pre-compiled DCU files, and may also have access to some source units (.pas files), and that one or more of the units that depends on other units, was compiled at a different time than now, with multiple versions of a common unit. I wish I could draw you a picture.

Imagine you have a car, and someone upgrades the engine, changing it from a V6 to a V8. Now someone who had previously been servicing your engine comes back and tries to find the place where the V6's exhaust manifold attached. It's not there any more, it's moved. Since the new engine is frozen in its current shape (stay with me here!), your service technician simply goes back to you (the customer) and says, "sorry, I'm confused, I can't continue, I give up". That's roughly what this error message means.

Cleaning it up is possible in several ways; It may be a simple matter for you to make sure you compile 100% from `.pas` files, and have no Library folders containing `.dcu` files at all. Of course, that's hardly ideal, is it, since the whole purpose of a Library path was to contain a precompiled "library" of DCU files.

So instead, I suggest you do a cleanup (delete all your DCU files) and rebuild all your component packages from source (you do have a batch file for that purpose right?) and then review both your project's search path, and library path to see that both contain only the folders you think they should contain.

Comment: great! I had installed JCL and JVCL with [these installers](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2011/11/updated-jcl-and-jvcl-binary-installers-for-xe2-2/) because I thought they would have solved an issue I had, but maybe they where compiled with a different version of the IDE and installers simply copied the DCUs without compiling sources with my IDE. Many thanks!

Comment: The binary installers are for users of the TRIAL version of Delphi only. (It says so clearly at the link you posted!) Glad that you solved it.  But if in future you used a weird installer, please note that in the question, or we'll assume you used the regular installer.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem with Delphi 2010 and XE3 (both on same PC while migrating).

After several hours of recompiling both my projects and the JCL projects (the installer bat file errors on my PC) discovered the problem was the order in which the directories were declared in the tools/options/Delphi Options/libraries.

Took them all out, added the version specific directory (eg lib\D14, lib\D17\Win32) and then the other JCL sub-directories required (ie one at a time until a project using JCL would build)

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix:

0. After JCL package install, reboot your PC to apply Path change. (The installer will ask for it.)
1. Open from Delphi IDE the JCL package. eg.: `..\jcl\packages\d7\Jcl.dpk`
2. Click Project menu > **Build !** (do not just compile)
3. Save all changes, close Delphi.

Now `JVCL\install.bat` should work fine. Tested just now with [Delphi7 Light Edition 7.3.4.3](https://www.code-projects.net/delphi-7-lite-full-edition-repack-7-3-4-3/)
*(You may also edit that .bat file and change the first line from `@echo off` to `echo on`, to see more detailed infos, what's going on.)*